# Cloudflare and caching sections users aren't allowed into

Tags: cloudflare

**This is just a question out of curiosity.**

How is it that Cloudflare is able to cache my admin panel? How do they do it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Cloudflare only caches files that should be static all the time (images, css, js, etc.). You can use Page Rules to configure caching of HTML; but, by default, Cloudflare should not cache user-specific markup.

[More info from Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-How-Do-I-Tell-Cloudflare-What-to-Cache-)